# jQuery's `getScript` fails. The path is correct, and the script was downloaded properly.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I wrote up a website using Mustache.js. The templates are loaded using AJAX via jQuery.

When I was running the website locally and testing, everything loaded fine. When I uploaded the site to my school server however, jQuery's `getScript` is reporting a failure to load `mustache.min.js`.

Whenever I need to run render a template, I'm using the following helper function:

```
doWithMustache: function(f) {
    $.getScript("./js/mustache.min.js", function() {
        f();

    }).fail(
        console.error("Failed to fetch mustache script.");
    );
}
```

and am using it like:

```
renderPage: function(uniqueBodyElement, lastModifiedDate) {
    var data;
    var headTemplate;
    var bodyTemplate;
    var articleTemplate;

    //Wait until all data is available
    $.when(
            $.get("./templates/siteData.json", function(d){ data = d }),
            $.get("./templates/HeadTemplate.mustache", function(hT){ headTemplate = hT }),
            $.get("./templates/BodyTemplate.mustache", function(bT){ bodyTemplate = bT }),
            $.get("./templates/ArticleTemplate.mustache", function(aT){ articleTemplate = aT })

    ).done(function() {
        Helpers.doWithMustache(function() {
            var partial = TemplateLoader.getTemplatePartial(uniqueBodyElement);
            partial.lastModifiedDate = lastModifiedDate;

            var renderedHead = Mustache.render(headTemplate, data);
            var renderedBody = Mustache.render(bodyTemplate, data, partial);

            var renderedArticleBody = Mustache.render(articleTemplate, data, { articleBody: renderedBody });

            $('head').append(renderedHead);
            $('body').html(renderedArticleBody);

            console.log("Templates Loaded.");
        });

    }).fail(function() {
        console.error("Failed to fetch templates or site data.")
    });

}
```

Locally, this worked as expected. After uploading it however, I'm getting console errors telling me that it "Failed to fetch mustache script". Unfortunately, `fail()` doesn't seem to report any errors, so I have no idea what's causing the problem.

The obvious issue would be that the path is wrong, but when I checked Edge's "Network" tab in "Developer Tools", everything, including the mustache script, is being loaded correctly:

[image]

I also verified this by changing the load path to something I knew was wrong. Not only did I get the failure to fetch error, I also got "Bad URI" errors.

So, I know the path is correct, but it still won't load the script.

Does anyone know what the problem may be, or how to get closer to finding it?

Comment: @jfriend00 Check the end of the question. Edge is reporting that that file was downloaded correctly, and I've independently verified that the path is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the anonymous function reference, right now you're **always** running the `console.log` and returning the result to `fail()` (which would be `undefined`).

Change it to

```
doWithMustache: function(f) {
    $.getScript("./js/mustache.min.js", function() {
        f();
    }).fail(function() {
        console.error("Failed to fetch mustache script.");
    });
}
```

Comment: You're right, which is actually unfortunate. The real problem is that Mustache isn't rendering, which I assumed was linked to the error. Since that's not the case though, I'm back to square 1 :/. Oh well, thank you for helping with this error.

Comment: @Carcigenicate - If you never get the `Templates Loaded` of `Failed to fetch templates...` log, the `renderPage` function is never called.

Comment: I get "Templates Loaded", and not "Failed to fetch...". The problem is that instead of Mustache plugging in the supplied data values, it's just replacing the mustache tags with empty strings. This is only happening once it's uploaded.

Comment: Sounds strange, but I'm not very familiar with the inner workings of Mustache. Try asking a new question specifically about that, someone that knows Mustache will probably be able to spot the issue ?

Comment: Thanks. I'm just trying last ditch efforts to diagnose it, but I'm not super familiar with how Mustache works either. I've verified the input, and checked the output, so it seems like somethings going wrong internally inside the mustache module.